# jquery client side button click is not refreshing all contents of the asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an issue with the asp.net button click event from the client side.

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveInput" runat="server"  Text="Save" CssClass="hidesave"/>
```

```js
$("body").on('click', "#<%= btnValidate.ClientID%>", function () {
                $('#<%= btnSaveInput.ClientID%>').click();
    });
```

on click on "btnValidate", jquery does a client click on "btnSaveInput". Save part is working fine, but there is a image url that changes from "Unsaved Information" to "Saved Information".

when i use "btnSaveInput" directly on the page, the saved image url is working fine. but when i use through jquery it is not refreshing all contents of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be that "btnValidate" is continuing to PostBack, you can stop it by adding `return false;` in your click event function, after the "btnSaveInput" click() call.  If for some reason that didn't fix it, maybe see if [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) helps (shown below).

Also, a little tip - I like to add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to controls to make JavaScript binding easier (just have to ensure there is only ever one instance of that ID -- so you wouldn't use it inside a Repeater, for example):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSaveInput" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

So your end result could be:

```
$('#btnValidate').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#btnSaveInput').click();

     return false;
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @scolija I go the answer. since this new button is in the update panel. i need to add the save button to  asyn post back trigger.